# Oracle SQL: Comparing Extracted Date in Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following `TABLE.Sample1`:

```
Col1(varchar) | Col2(timestamp) 
---------------------------------------
A             | 08-NOV-16 09.59.52.000000000 AM
B             | 08-NOV-16 10.05.12.000000000 AM
C             | 09-NOV-16 10.05.12.000000000 AM
```

Suppose I want to get all rows given a date in the format of `DD MON YYYY`.

Here's my initial query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Sample1 
 WHERE CAST(Col2 as DATE) = TO_DATE('8 NOV 2016','DD MON YYYY');
```

I'm curious as to why this query doesn't work on equality(`=`) but works fine on inequalities ( `>`, `<`, `<=`, `>=`, `<>`). Am I not comparing the same data types here?

I ended up using `TO_CHAR` function to make this work but it begs the question, is there a simpler or more direct approach to this?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Sample1 
 WHERE TO_CHAR(CAST(Col2 as DATE)) = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('8 NOV 2016','DD MON YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle a `DATE` value still has a time. `CAST(Col2 as DATE)` won't change that.

You can use `trunc()` to set the time part of a `date` (or `timestamp`) to `00:00:00` and you shouldn't compare strings, but dates:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sample1 
WHERE trunc(col2) = TO_DATE('8 NOV 2016','DD MON YYYY');
```

But I strongly recommend to **not** use a date format like that. It depends on the NLS settings of the SQL *client* program and might fail with different language settings.

I prefer using ANSI SQL date literals:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sample1 
WHERE trunc(col2) = DATE '2016-11-08';
```

In both cases, the date will have a time of `00:00:00` because none was given and thus the comparison will work.

Note that `trunc(col2)` will not be able to use an index on `col2`. If performance is important you should either use a range query `where col2 >= DATE '2016-11-08' and col2 < DATE '2016-11-09'` or create a function based index on `trunc(col2)`.